# Joomla showing a blank screen with only "Error" on it after turning on Debug

Tags: error-handling, fatal-error, debug

I've seen blank screen with only "Error" before, but none was like this time.

1. It only happens when I turn on Debug from Global Configuration; after turning it off, it happens no more;
2. If I set error reporting to maximum, the error message turns from just "Error" to "Error: Unclosed comment.: Unclosed comment."
3. There is no error logged in my Apache system.
4. I cloned the whole server to a new IP, the symptom persists.

I have a backup of this site about 1 month ago, and it doesn't have this problem. I uninstalled all of the extensions that I remember were installed during this period, but the error still occurs.
Does anyone have any idea of what may cause this issue? And can someone explain to me why this critical error is not logged in my Apache system?

Comment: I have seen this when the PHP version has been raised.  What version are you on?  If you drop a version, does the issue persist?

Comment: Yes it persists.

Comment: Can you try raising the error level to `development`?

Comment: So development is larger than "maximum"? I did but the outcome is nothing different